# total path probability of weighted circular graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, probability, fractions, fractals

Let's say there is a game where for each move there are probable paths, depending on the throw of  fancy dice. Depending on the results there might be transitions forward, backward or staying on one place. Eventually (even after infinite amount of throws) the graph leads to final states. Each edge is weighted with probability .

For the case where there are no loops I can simply sum+multiply and re-normalize the probabilities for each outcome if I start at the same vertex(cell).

However, if I have loops it starts getting confusing. For example, let's say we have same probability on each edge:

```
  start0
   /\   ^
  /  \  |
end1  tr2
      /
     end2
```

the graph starts at **start0** and has 50% chance of terminating at **end1** or going to transition **tr2**. From **tr2** there is again 50% chance terminating at **end2** or going back to **start0**.

How could I calculate the total probability for reaching each stop **end1** and **end2**. If I try using a converging series like this:

pEnd1=1/2 + 1/2*1/2+1/8+.. ->lim->1. which makes no sense since **end2** is getting no probability. Obviously I have a mistake there.

So my question is how can I calculate the probabilities of reaching the final nodes if I have the probabilities of each edge but I could have loops.

example 1) simple fork with a loop all edges are 50% probable

```
start0-> p=50% ->end1
start0-> p=50% ->tr1
tr2-> p=50% ->start0
tr2-> p=50% ->end2
```

example 2) more loops

```
start0-> p=1/3 ->e1
start0-> p=1/3 ->tr1
start0-> p=1/3 ->start0
tr1-> p=1/3 ->tr2
tr1-> p=2/3 ->start0
tr2-> p=7/9 ->start0
tr2-> p=2/9 ->end2
```

**example 3**) - degenerate test case - since all paths end at **e1** - it should end up having 100% 
probability

```
start0-> p=1/3 ->e1
start0-> p=2/3 ->tr1
tr1-> p=3/4 ->start0
tr2-> p=1/4 ->e1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really a programming problem, although you could write a simulation and perform it 100000 times to see what the distribution would be.

You wrote:

> pEnd1=1/2 + 1/2*1/2+1/8+.. ->lim->1. which makes no sense since end2 is getting no probability. Obviously I have a mistake there.

Indeed, there is a mistake. You did not take into account the probability to go from tr2 to start0 (50%). The probability that the path will cycle once to start0 and then end up in end1 is 1/2 (going to tr2) * 1/2 (going back to start0) * 1/2 (going to end1). The number of decisions (of 50%) is always *odd* when ending up in end1. And it is *even* when ending up in end2. So the formula would be:

pEnd1 = 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-3</sup> + 2<sup>-5</sup> + ... -> lim = 2/3

pEnd2 = 2<sup>-2</sup> + 2<sup>-4</sup> + 2<sup>-6</sup> + ... -> lim = 1/3

#### Simulation

To make this a programming question, here is a simulation in JavaScript:

```js
function run(transitions, state) {
    while (transitions[state][state] != 1) { // not in sink
        let probs = transitions[state];
        let rnd = Math.random(); // in range [0, 1)
        for (let i = 0; i < probs.length; i++) {
            rnd -= probs[i];
            if (rnd < 0) {
                state = i; // transition
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return state;
}

// Define graph
let names = ["start0", "end1", "tr2", "end2"]
let transitions = [
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], // sink
    [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]  // sink
];

// Start sampling
let numResults = [0, 0, 0, 0];
let numSamples = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    let endstate = run(transitions, 0);
    numSamples++;
    numResults[endstate]++;
    document.querySelector("#" + names[endstate]).textContent = (100 * numResults[endstate] / numSamples).toFixed(4) + "%";
}, 1);
```

```html
<div>Arriving in end1: <span id="end1"></span></div>
<div>Arriving in end2: <span id="end2"></span></div>
```

You may also like to read about [Absorbing Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain). From that we learn that the "absorbing probabilities" matrix B can be calculated with the formula:

B = NR

Where:

- N is the "fundamental matrix" (I - Q)⁻¹
- I is the identity matrix of the same shape as Q
- Q is the probability matrix for transitions between non-final states
- R is the probability matrix for transitions to final states

Here is a script (including the relevant matrix functions) to calculate B for the example problem you depicted:

```js
// Probabilities to go from one non-final state to another
let Q = [
    [0.0, 0.5], // from start0 to [start0, tr2]
    [0.5, 0.0]  // from tr2    to [tr2, start0]
];
// Probabilities to go from one non-final state to a final one
let R = [
    [0.5, 0.0], // from start0 to [end1, end2]
    [0.0, 0.5]  // from tr2    to [end1, end2]
];
// See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Absorbing_probabilities
let N = inversed(sum(identity(Q.length), scalarProduct(Q, -1)));
let B = product(N, R);
console.log("B = (I-Q)⁻¹R:\n" + str(B));

// Generic matrix utility functions:
// cofactor is copy of given matrix without given column and given row 
function cofactor(a, y, x) {
    return a.slice(0, y).concat(a.slice(y+1)).map(row => row.slice(0, x).concat(row.slice(x+1)));
} 

function determinant(a) {
    return a.length == 1 ? a[0][0] : a.reduceRight((sum, row, y) =>
        a[y][0] * determinant(cofactor(a, y, 0)) - sum
    , 0);
} 

function adjoint(a) {
    return a.length == 1 ? [[1]] : transposed(a.map((row, y) => 
        row.map((_, x) => ((x + y) % 2 ? -1 : 1) * determinant(cofactor(a, y, x)))
    ));
} 

function transposed(a) {
    return a[0].map((_, x) => a.map((_, y) => a[y][x]));
}

function scalarProduct(a, coeff) {
    return a.map((row, y) => row.map((val, x) => val * coeff));
}

function inversed(a) {
    return scalarProduct(adjoint(a), 1 / determinant(a));
}

function product(a, b) {
    return a.map((rowa) =>
        b[0].map((_, x) =>
            b.reduce((sum, rowb, z) =>
                sum + rowa[z] * rowb[x]
            , 0)
        )
    );
}

function sum(a, b) {
    return a.map((row, y) => row.map((val, x) => val + b[y][x]));
}

function identity(length) {
    return Array.from({length}, (_, y) => 
        Array.from({length}, (_, x) => +(y == x))
    );
}

function str(a) {
    return a.map(row => JSON.stringify(row)).join("\n");
}
```

The output is:

```js
[
    [2/3, 1/3] // probabilities when starting in start0 and ending in [end1, end2]
    [1/3, 2/3] // probabilities when starting in tr2 and ending in [end1, end2]
]
```

Comment: You sir gave a really impressive answer, even with code snippets ( i was just asking for the algorithm) which will take me some time to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a discrete-time discrete-state-space [Absorbing Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).

In your example, end 1 and end2 are absorbing states.

The referenced Wikipedia article describes how to calculate absorbing probabilities (or absorption probabilities).

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457848/probability-of-absorption-in-markov-chain) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEsUsaK1HBk).